# $_POST checkbox in order list. Email

Tags: php, html, email, checkbox

So basically I got a checkout page with multiple items with a checkbox on it, Let's say you want 4 items out of 15, when you check those boxes those specific items get added to the order list that gets sent to you mail.

I haven't set a value to the checkboxes yet because I'm trying to figure this out.

It's a **wall of text**, I know that. jsFiddle is acting retarded to the code I'm submiting.

PHP $_POST

```
$basic_standby = trim(htmlentities($_POST['basic_standby'], ENT_QUOTES));
$advanced_standby = trim(htmlentities($_POST['advanced_standby'], ENT_QUOTES));
$basic_game_overlay = trim(htmlentities($_POST['basic_game_overlay'], ENT_QUOTES));
$advanced_game_overlay = trim(htmlentities($_POST['advanced_game_overlay'], ENT_QUOTES));
$desktop_overlay = trim(htmlentities($_POST['desktop_overlay'], ENT_QUOTES));
$offline_overlay = trim(htmlentities($_POST['offline_overlay'], ENT_QUOTES));
$live_overlay = trim(htmlentities($_POST['live_overlay'], ENT_QUOTES));
$avatar_image = trim(htmlentities($_POST['avatar_image'], ENT_QUOTES));
$description_images = trim(htmlentities($_POST['description_images'], ENT_QUOTES));
$team_logo = trim(htmlentities($_POST['team_logo'], ENT_QUOTES));
$gold_package = trim(htmlentities($_POST['gold_package'], ENT_QUOTES));
$website_design = trim(htmlentities($_POST['website_design'], ENT_QUOTES));
```

Mail HTML/PHP

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="670" class="content">
    <tr>
        <td width="100"></td>
        <td style="padding: 5px 0 20px 0; font-size: 13px;"><b style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px;">Order list:</b><br /><br /> '. $faster_delivery .'<br /> '. $basic_standby .'<br /> '. $advanced_standby .'<br /> '. $basic_game_overlay .'<br /> '. $advanced_game_overlay .'<br /> '. $desktop_overlay .'<br /> '. $offline_overlay .'<br /> '. $live_overlay .'<br /> '. $avatar_image .'<br /> '. $description_images .'<br /> '. $team_logo .'<br /> '. $gold_package .'<br /> '. $website_design .'</td>
        <td width="100"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Few checkboxes - HTML

```
<tr>
    <td width="250">1x Basic standby overlay:</td>
    <td width="15" align="left">
        <input class="test" type="checkbox" name="basic_standby" value="0" data-val="10" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="250">1x Advanced standby overlay:</td>
    <td width="15" align="left">
        <input type="checkbox" name="advanced_standby" value="0" data-val="20" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="250">1x Basic game overlay:</td>
    <td width="15" align="left">
        <input type="checkbox" name="basic_game_overlay" value="0" data-val="10" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="250">1x Advanced game overlay:</td>
    <td width="15" align="left">
        <input type="checkbox" name="advanced_game_overlay" value="0" data-val="20" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

My error message

```
Notice: Undefined index: basic_standby in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined variable: newsletter in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined index: advanced_standby in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 48

Notice: Undefined index: basic_game_overlay in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 52

Notice: Undefined index: advanced_game_overlay in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined index: offline_overlay in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined index: live_overlay in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 68

Notice: Undefined index: avatar_image in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 72

Notice: Undefined index: description_images in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 76

Notice: Undefined index: website_design in C:\xampp\htdocs\datoverlayguy\core\includes\send_order.php on line 88
```

---

**EDIT**

When I try to send the email It shows like this.

[Gyazo link](http://i.gyazo.com/3dcc72518e4e59ed6a087fac516f6933.png)

[Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7NQq.png)

Comment: are you checking the form was posted before you process $_POST ?

Comment: You do have form tags, *right?*

Comment: Define variables and set empty value.

Comment: The form and the email sender in in the same file, everything is in one page. I do have form tags that leads no where. `<form method="post" action="">` @Dagon

Comment: can you do a var_dump($_POST) before you actually try to use the post variable just to check what's inside and post it ?

Comment: your top code will be processed and output the error even if the form has yet to be posted, thats the problem

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UUjXxvX8 the full page. @Dagon

Comment: @Alex http://pastebin.com/m61bxEi4 the `var_dump`

Comment: Also I edited a image to the main post how the email looks. Blanks from the empty posts and a 0 for the checked ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i get it....you set the values of your checkboxes to 0.

Meaning if they're check, the value sent will be "0"....if you don't check them....the value will be....wait for it....."0" also considered as false.

You have to set something like that :

That's way if you check the box you can do :

```
if( isset($_POST['advanced_game_overlay']) )
    $advanced_game_overlay = $_POST['advanced_game_overlay'];
```

And then you can use the variable in your form, it should display 1 if the box is checked, 0 if it's not. Try it, it might solve the issue. In your dump we see the value "sticka" which is sent so your form informations are successfuly sent, you also reuse the "name" attrib from your inputs so there's nothing else i can think of except that...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59316/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-post-checkbox-in-order-list-email).